# Need a JS framework that works with HTML5 <audio>. Which ones don't create or destroy views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, html5-audio

One of the quirks with the < audio > tag is that it must be embedded in the page when it loads and it must not be destroyed and recreated.

Can anyone tell me if Backbone.js or one of the many other MV* frameworks load pages so that the < audio > tag stays on the page?

Thanks and long live stackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

The audio element does not need to be added to the DOM at all to play in most modern browsers.      In fact, I think even IE9 no longer requires that.  It has been a couple months since I last did a round of tests, but I work with HTML audio every day.  Do you have a specific case where this is a problem?

Backbone won't destroy any elements on the page unless you tell it to.  Even if you attached your view to the body, you could still write the render function to not be destructive to what was already there.

Comment: I don't have a test case, but the problem (iOS - iPhone,iPad) was that the onended event wasn't firing reliably unless it was added to the DOM (and not removed, hidden, etc). Hence, playing a list of songs would hang after the first track finished.

Comment: Using my [audio test page](http://agilepro.com/audiotestsuite/) I see the ended event reliably on both my iPad and iPod Touch.  The elements are loaded via javascript after the page is loaded and aren't appended to the page unless you click the append button.  Maybe simplify down and see where the inconsistency turns up?